# SQL Query To Find Users Not Signed In Over Last 120 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, null

Using SQL Server.  I have two tables, both with a column called UserID.  The first is one called Users, the second is one called Audits.  The Users table has a list of 716 distinct users, and my goal is to find all users who HAVE NOT shown up in the Audits table in the last 120 days (there is a column called DateTime on the Audits table).  Running the query:

```
Select distinct UserID
from Audits
Where DateTime > GETDATE() -120
```

I get 315 results back.  I know I can compare that with the 716 UserID fields on the Users table, but I'm struggling to get that figured out, and I'd like to give this to my customer to be able to run whenever they want to see which of their users they may want to disable.  This is what I tried:

```
Select *
from Users
Where UserID Not In
    (select distinct UserID
    from Audits
    where DateTime > GETDATE() -120)
```

This returned 0 results, not 415...  I thought maybe I needed to specify the columns, so I also tried:

```
Select *
from Users
Where Users.UserID Not In
    (select distinct Audits.UserID
    from Audits
    where Audits.DateTime > GETDATE() -120)
```

Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 1):

> This returned 0 results, not 415

May be the audits table contain records having UserID = NULL, in which case `NOT IN` will simply fail. You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Audits
    WHERE Audits.UserID = Users.UserID
    AND Audits.DateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -120, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below:

```
select u.* from 
           (select * from audit where lastlogin > GETDATE() -120 )a 
             right outer join users u
             on a.userId = u.userId
 where a.userId is null
```